# Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php

> ERROR is : Fatal error: Call to undefined function Connect_DB() in
>   C:\wamp\www\movie\movies.php on line 12

config.php :

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);

class Connection{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $db = "movies";
    private $connect;
    private $q;

    function Conn(){
        $this->connect = @mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
        return $this->connect;
    }

    function Select(){
        mysql_unbuffered_query('SET NAMES utf8');
        return mysql_select_db($this->db);
    }

    function Query($sql){
        $this->q = mysql_query($sql);
        return $this->q;
    }

    function Rows(){
        return mysql_num_rows($this->q);
    }

    function Object(){
        return mysql_fetch_object($this->q);
    }
}
?>
```

movies.php:

```
<?php
class Movies{
    function Connect_DB(){
        $data = new Connection;
        if(!($data->Conn())) header("Location: 404.php");
        if(!($data->Select())) header("Location: 404.php");
        return $data;
    }
    function getImdb(){
        $q = "SELECT * FROM top250";
        $data = Connect_DB();
        $ch = $data->Query($q);
        if($ch){
            $i=0;
            while($r = $data->Object()){
                $result["name"][$i] = $r->name;
                $result["genre"][$i] = $r->genre;
                $result["imdb"][$i] = $r->imdb;
                $result["year"][$i] = $r->year;
                $result["releaseDate"][$i] = $r->releaseDate;
                $result["country"][$i] = $r->country;
                $result["imgPath"][$i] = $r->imgPath;
                $i++;
            }//while
            return $q;
        }else{
            $result = false;
            return $result;
        }//else
    }//getImdb
}
?>
```

Here is html file:

```
<?php
require "config.php";
require "movies.php";
$imdb = new Movies;
$result = $imdb->getImdb();

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
.....
```

I couldn't find where error is ? I have 2 class (config.php and movies.php) Config.php has mysql connection settings and movies has getting a table from mysql and html file include 2 file and show table. Can someone help me ?

Comment: `$data = $this->Connect_DB();`...

Comment: thanks, i missed it. simple mistake ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not calling CONNECT_DB correctly. In a class when you want to call another method we use $this->method(). So change the line `$data = Connect_DB();` to `$data = $this->Connect_DB();`